# js file isn't loading when switching pages in react router

Tags: javascript, react-router

I have a calendar app that loads the calendar when i switch to that page in react, but when i switch to home and then back to the calendar the calendar is not being uploaded.

calendar:

```
import generateCal from './js/generateCal'; 
export default function calendarContent() {
    return (
    <div id="cal">
        //Calendar would be printed here
    </div> 
)}
```

JS file for calendar:

```
window.onload = prntCal;
function prntCal() {
docuemnt.getElementById("cal").innerHTML = "uploaded";
}
```

Routing:

```
<Router>
    <Header />
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/home' exact component={Home} />
      <Route path='/calendar' component={Calendar} />
    </Switch>
    <Footer />
  </Router>
```

Comment: Where is anything getting uploaded?

Comment: typo in prntCal: `docuemnt`

Comment: no, the name is right, but it only runs once, when the DOM is loaded but not when components are switched